# How to apply pointer-events:none; to one side of the div after rotating it?

Tags: html, css

I have a flip card (a div with `transform: rotateY(180deg);` on mouse hover). Some elements from the front side of the div interfere with mouse hover effect of elements on the back side of the div.

Is there a way to apply `pointer-events:none;` to the front side of the card after the card is flipped? I would do something like `.back-side:hover .front-side{pointer-events:none;}` but I can't do it because .back-side nd .front-side are 2 different divs next to each other, and not parent and child elements.

Comment: Can you put them in a container fit to them and use `:hover` on that container as a selector for both the flip and `pointer-events: none` (or even apply `pointer-events: none` to the front at all times if it isn’t supposed to be interacted with)? And is the backface of the front side visible, e.g. a semitransparent back side?

Comment: @Ry- that is the problem - the front side should be interactive until I see the backside. There are buttons on both sides. The problem is that after flipping the card, the buttons and other divs from the front side interfere with buttons on the back side, in such a way that I can't click them or see the mouse hover effect. That's why I'm looking for a way to disable mouse events on the front side, but only when I look at the back side.

Comment: Although you didn’t confirm backface visibility one way or the other, does applying `backface-visibility: hidden;` to both sides achieve what you want?

Comment: I have backface-visibility: hidden; for both sides, but for some reason still have this problem. I managed to solve it using the hover effect as in the answer below. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `front-side` div after `back-side` div, like this:

```
<div class="back-side"></div>    
<div class="front-side"></div>
```

and add this style:

```
.back-side:hover + .front-side{pointer-events:none;}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked thank you very much! I tried it before but didn't realize that the back side div should go before the front side iv for this to work. Thank you again!